# Position relative and absolute does not work in ngFor

Tags: css, angular

I have table where i need to have nested radio buttons and i can select just one of them so for that purpose i have

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="ritemb" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
}
```

and it works.

But i need to change the color of the selected radio buttons so i googled and found this solution

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
            <td>
                <div class="radio-item">
                    <input type="radio" id="ritemb" name="ritem" value="ropt2">
                    <label for="ritemb">Option 2</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
}


.radio-item {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 6px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
  }
  
  .radio-item input[type='radio'] {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .radio-item label {
    color: #666;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .radio-item label:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    border: 2px solid #004c97;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .radio-item input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    border-radius: 11px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: 10px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    background: red;
  }
```

but now eve i click on the last adio butons, the first radio button is maked red instead the selected one. I suppose the problem is in the css positions but i can't find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your struggle is that your `id` did not change, and also not the associated `label`. By using the interpolation feature from Angular, it is possible to generate a "predictable" `id` for each radio button.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
            <td>
                <div class="radio-item">
                    <input type="radio" id="ritemb{{i}}" name="ritem" value="ropt2">
                    <label for="ritemb{{i}}">Option {{i}}</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As per the Mozilla documentation on [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio):

> They each also have a unique id, which is used by the  element's for attribute to associate the labels with the radio buttons.

With a unique `label` and `id` per radio button it should work as desired.

Comment: why it works without unique id and without position relative and absolute then ?

Comment: Can one say it **worked** if only the first radio button would show as selected? With no unique id, the first radio button would always get checked and the other matching elements with the identical id would be ignored. My query is: did my proposed solution solve your problem?